# Azure-Service-Bus: How can I access a message in the processMessage() function?

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus

I am not familiar with JAVA and struggling for days now understanding one particular issue.
I want to receive messages from the Azure Cloud and I am using the Azure-Service-Bus.

According to [azure-service-bus documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions) I have build a java file which looks like this:

```
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.*;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

static String connectionString = "<NAMESPACE CONNECTION STRING>";
static String topicName = "<TOPIC NAME>";    
static String subName = "<SUBSCRIPTION NAME>";

// handles received messages
static void receiveMessages() throws InterruptedException
{
    CountDownLatch countdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    // Create an instance of the processor through the ServiceBusClientBuilder
    ServiceBusProcessorClient processorClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(connectionString)
        .processor()
        .topicName(topicName)
        .subscriptionName(subName)
        .processMessage(ServiceBusTopicTest::processMessage)
        .processError(context -> processError(context, countdownLatch))
        .buildProcessorClient();

    System.out.println("Starting the processor");
    processorClient.start();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    System.out.println("Stopping and closing the processor");
    processorClient.close();        
}

private static void processMessage(ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext context) {
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = context.getMessage();
    System.out.printf("Processing message. Session: %s, Sequence #: %s. Contents: %s%n", message.getMessageId(),
        message.getSequenceNumber(), message.getBody());
}

private static void processError(ServiceBusErrorContext context, CountDownLatch countdownLatch) {
    System.out.printf("Error when receiving messages from namespace: '%s'. Entity: '%s'%n",
        context.getFullyQualifiedNamespace(), context.getEntityPath());

    if (!(context.getException() instanceof ServiceBusException)) {
        System.out.printf("Non-ServiceBusException occurred: %s%n", context.getException());
        return;
    }

    ServiceBusException exception = (ServiceBusException) context.getException();
    ServiceBusFailureReason reason = exception.getReason();

    if (reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.MESSAGING_ENTITY_DISABLED
        || reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.MESSAGING_ENTITY_NOT_FOUND
        || reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.UNAUTHORIZED) {
        System.out.printf("An unrecoverable error occurred. Stopping processing with reason %s: %s%n",
            reason, exception.getMessage());

        countdownLatch.countDown();
    } else if (reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.MESSAGE_LOCK_LOST) {
        System.out.printf("Message lock lost for message: %s%n", context.getException());
    } else if (reason == ServiceBusFailureReason.SERVICE_BUSY) {
        try {
            // Choosing an arbitrary amount of time to wait until trying again.
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to sleep for period of time");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Error source %s, reason %s, message: %s%n", context.getErrorSource(),
            reason, context.getException());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
    receiveMessages();
}
```

Everything works well so far and the messages from Azure are printed in the console-log.
Nevertheless my goal is to save the messages in a variable/array-list which I want to create in the `main()` function. So I tried to return the messages in the `processMessage()` function to the `main()` function, but it doesn't work since it is a static void class. I also tried to create an array-list variable and pass it to the `processMessage()` function, but I didn't get how to pass the array-list variable in the `processClient` creation.

I am using a Low-Code Plattform called Mendix and want to implement this custom java code and just struggling with passing the messages in to an array-list to the `main()` function.

Can someone help me or give me a hint how to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Ömer

Answer (score -1):

> So I tried to return the messages in the processMessage() function to
> the main() function, but it doesn't work since it is a static void
> class.

Since you want to get the message in a variable type or a array list type, then just make the return type as below:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("---------This is the returnString()---------");
    System.out.println(returnString());
    System.out.println("---------This is the returnArrayList()---------");
    System.out.println(returnArrayList());
}
public static String returnString(){
    //For example is the message you get.
    String message = "some message";
    return message;
}
public static ArrayList returnArrayList(){
    //For example is the message you get.
    ArrayList<String> arlist = new ArrayList<String>( );
    arlist.add("JAVA");
    arlist.add("Csharp");
    arlist.add("Python");
    arlist.add("Php");
    arlist.add("Android");
    arlist.add("HTML");
    return arlist;
}
```